Connect two overlapping planes in Editmode GIS-Tool
I'm still very new to Blender and unfortunately I'm failing at something that is actually quite easy.
I want to connect two overlapping planes so that only four vertices are created. I'm not allowed to move the planes, as there is map material mapped onto them. I can connect them via Join, but in editmode they are still two separate planes (8 vertices).
Background: I use the GIS tool and would like to embed a fairly large area with the highest zoom level in Blender. Unfortunately, I have not yet managed to load the maps in loggt mode as a single plane in Blender. So I want to select the area individually with e at level 17/18 and then select the next monitor section (etc.). This works wonderfully, you can generate large areas at a very good zoom level, but the giz-toll overlaps the planes. When I load the height data and confirm the modifiers, I get a lot of faces at the overlaps. I would therefore like to connect them cleanly beforehand.
Do you know of a way to do this? Remesh and Boolen did not work.
Thank you!
LG
Adrian

If you have overlapping vertices you should be able to merge them by selecting them and then hitting M > Merge by Distance.

yes, I tried that. Unfortunately I can only set the value to 50m . But the plane is several kilometers long. Unfortunately nothing happens.

Merge by distance is really only intended to merge vertices right on top of or very close to each other. The other options on that menu are for groups or pairs of vertices and do what the menu says! This is the Blender manual section on merging.
